# Passing Encoded Slashes to a WebServiceHost service

Tags: c#, encoding, url-encoding

I'm hosting a service and trying to pass it a url as a parameter ... I know I've got to encode the url - but when I put a break point inside my method it only gets hit if I pass certain encodings - not others such a forward slash ...

So ...

http://myurl.com:8181/blah

works fine - even something like (encoded colon) ...

http://myurl.com:8181/blah%3A

but if I try to pass an encoded slash

http://myurl.com:8181/blah%2F

I get 'Endpoint not found' and my breakpoint isn't hit ...

Can anyone assist please?

Code below ...

---

Hosting the service ...

```
var instantPrintService = new WebServiceHost(typeof(InstantPrintService), new Uri("http://myurl:8181/"));

instantPrintService.Open();
```

The interface ....

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInstantPrint
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "printlabel/{filepath}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
    Response PrintLabel(string filepath);
}
```

The print label method ...

```
    public Response PrintLabel(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            return new Response { Success = true, Message = "Success" };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Response { Success = false, Message = ex.ToString() };
        }

    }
```